# Trying to resolve errors when creating package version

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

I'm currently getting the following errors when I'm creating a package version:

```
(1) Case.RMA: Picklist value: Chat in picklist: Origin not found
(2) Case.Case: Picklist value: Chat in picklist: Origin not found
(3) Case.Standard Support Process: Picklist value: Waiting on Customer not found
```

My local metadata includes the two Case record types (`RMA` is a custom one I created), the Case's `Origin` pick list field and the `Standard Support Process` businessProcess.  Is there something else I need to include to resolve these errors?

UPDATE
So far, I've added the Case Origin field and the CaseOrigin StandardValueSet to my metadata.  The packaging process is now complaining about the Case Priority field, so I've added the Priority field and the CasePriority StandardValueSet to my metadata as well.  Currently attempting a new package version.

Comment: As you've observed, you're missing the StandardValueSet values. Once those are in your package folders, your version creation should go just fine.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was.  I'm learning the hard way that by modifying the Case object, I need to bring in a lot of ancillary meta data.